# Sun Studio 10 has strange `sun` constant?

Tags: c++, sunstudio

Strangely, the following C++ program compiles on Sun Studio 10 without producing a warning for an undefined variable:

```
int main()
{
  return sun;
}
```

The value of `sun` seems to be 1. Where does this variable come from and what is it for?

Comment: It's for counting suns, and there is only the one of them, hence it's 1. Have you tried `return stars;`? You'll need something bigger than an int though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's almost certainly a predefined macro.  Formally, the C and
C++ standards reserve names starting with an underscore and
a capital letter, or containing two underscores, for this, but
practically, compilers had such symbols defined before the
standard, and continue to support them, at least in their
non-compliant modes which is the default mode for all of the
compilers I know.  I can remember having problems with `linux'
at one time, but not when I invoked g++ with -std=c++89.

Answer (score 2):

It must be one of the automatic macros created by the compiler.

Try the same thing, replace `sun` by `gnu` and use a gcc compiler on Linux. You'll get a similar result.

With gcc, you can get all the predefined macros with: `echo "" | gcc -E - -dM`.

Comment: Using GCC on Solaris here did produce an error as expected. I always thought these macros were of the form `__GNUC__` or `__SUNPRO_CC` to avoid polluting the namespace.

Comment: Thank you, the second hint helped, I can see now that gcc sets the macros `sun`, `unix` and `sparc` to 1. It is a bit annoying, though, I think. Anybody has a reference where these come from?

Comment: Found it myself:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System_002dspecific-Predefined-Macros.html#System_002dspecific-Predefined-Macros

Answer (score 1):

`sun` is defined for historical backwards compatibility from before the convention to start with an underscore was adopted.  For Studio, it's documented in the cc(1) and CC(1) man pages under the -D flag:

```
   -Dname[=def]

       Defines  a  macro  symbol  name  to  the preprocessor.  Doing so is
       equivalent to including a #define directive at the beginning of the
       source.  You can use multiple -D options.

       The following values are predefined.

       SPARC and x86 platforms:


         __ARRAYNEW
         __BUILTIN_VA_ARG_INCR
         __DATE__
         __FILE__
         __LINE__
         __STDC__ = 0
         __SUNPRO_CC = 0x5130
         __SUNPRO_CC_COMPAT = 5 or G
         __TIME__
         __cplusplus
         __has_attribute
         __sun
         __unix
         _BOOL if type bool is enabled (see "-features=[no%]bool")
         _WCHAR_T
         sun
         unix
         __SVR4 (Oracle Solaris)
         __SunOS_5_10  (Oracle Solaris)
         __SunOS_5_11  (Oracle Solaris)
...
```

Various standards compliance options can disable it, as can the `+p` flag to CC.